# UITextView not displaying text after removal

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextview

I have a simple view controller that displays an `UITextView` and an `UILabel`. The controls are added on storyboard and connected as outlet's to the proper view controller code. They are filled with text on storyboard and they work correctly, when tested.

**But then I tried to remove controls from superview and then add them again as the subview, so basically I should be in the same state as before.**

The code of the view controller is below.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.textView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];

    [self.label removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
}

@end
```

But the result of the following code is that `UITextView` (`textView` variable) is **not displayed**, but the label is. If I print out the contents of `self.view.subviews` and `self.textView` after the code in `viewWillAppear` is executed, the `UITextView` is in hierarchy and also has correct frame. But the text is not visible at all.

I've also tried:

- set text in code again
- set background of `UITextView` in code
- calling `setNeedsDisplay` on `UITextView`

Nothing gets `UITextView` back, even though it exists in memory. My solution is now to allocate another `UITextView` in code, but it is a much slower operation.

**So, what is wrong here? Is it a bug in `UITextView`? Why does this code work with `UILabel` and not with `UITextView`?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the outlet is connected. Grey circle on the left should be filled as showed below:

[image]

You can connect it again by ctrl-dragging. You can also confirm it by checking if `self.textView` isn't nil.

Comment: That is the first thing I checked. If outlet wouldn't be connected, removeFromSuperview would not work. So it is not a problem.

Comment: @Legoless: have you tried changing the font color in the textview? Can you also check if the text view's frame has the correct origin and size?